# Python3 Pandas - how to merge two DataFrames that contain multiple rows with the same key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, inner-join

I am attempting to merge two DataFrames via their matching keys, but the keys may occur multiple (**n**) times in each DataFrame. The inner join gives rows for all **n^2** pairings of keys - instead, I want **n** rows.

*For some context:*  Imagine a check-in/check-out scenario for a library, where a book may be checked in, which is recorded in df1, or checked out, and recorded in df2. Each book has a unique key, but may be checked-in/out multiple times. Also, as the datasets only span a certain time window, some books may have a check-in record but not a check-out (books that had been checked out before the data was recorded), or a check-out record but not a check-in (books that have yet to be returned). My goal is to create a new DataFrame that only includes rows where there is both a check-in and corresponding check-out.

So, to finally get to my questions:

*1) How can I perform an inner join, where the first check-in is combined with first check-out, second check-in with second check-out, etc? By default, it gives all combinations - so if there are **n** check-ins and **n** check-outs, I get **n^2** rows instead of the **n** rows that I want.* (For now, let's ignore the possibility that a check-out precedes the first check-in, or an unequal number of check-ins/check-outs.) A simple example is below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1', 'A2','A2', 'A3'], 'DATE': [1, 1,2, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A2', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4'], 'DATE': [3, 5, 5, 7]})
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='ID',sort=True)
```

[image: example script]

Note that I get 4 entries for A2 and 1 for A3, whereas I only want rows 0 and 2 for A2 along with row 4 for A3.

```
df_wanted = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A2', 'A2', 'A3'], 'DATE_x': [1, 2, 2], 'DATE_y': [3, 5, 5]})
```

*2) The full case. Each check-in and check-out should be paired, with each check-out being paired with the check-in that is nearest before it. So if there are check-ins on days 1 and 2, and check-outs on days 0, 3 and 5, the only rows in the final df should correspond to the second two check-ins (days 1,2) and second two check-outs (days 3,5).*

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1', 'A2','A2', 'A3'], 'DATE': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A2', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4','A2'], 'DATE': [3, 5, 5, 7, 0]})
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='ID',sort=True)
```

I added a check-out at day 0 to df2. Now in df, I get 6 entries for A2 (and the one for A3), whereas I only want 2 entries for A2 (and the one for A3). This should result in the same `df_wanted` as above.

NOTE: the posted answer will match check-ins from days 1,2 to checkouts on days 0,3 rather than checkouts on days 3,5. So full solution will need to ensure date of checkout >= date of check-in, or start the counter at earliest check-in, or something similar.

*What I have tried:*
I tried implementing various combinations of `df.drop_duplicates()`, but I end up with the incorrect combinations. I also tried doing this manually by looping through all IDs which are common to both datasets (`common=set(df1.ID.values) & set(df2.ID.values)`), pairing them up by their order of occurrence, and then adding them to a new df one-by-one, but this seems rather inefficient.

This seems like a common enough task that there might be a more "pythonic" way of handling this?

Thanks for taking the time, and I appreciate any guidance or tips with this.

Comment: Please post code as actual code blocks and not screenshots - it really helps more people understand the problem and try to help with it by having something they can copy/paste to their environment.

Comment: You can do it with merge() function in R software. The you can write a csv file and read it with python. I just give you the fastest solution.

Comment: You say "Finally, if this is easier in SQL etc" - it *might* be - but don't forget we can't see the attempts you've tried all the results you've got regarding using pandas for that etc... So again, you need to help us to help you there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Jon, I'm still new at this. I'll edit the post to include code blocks and results of my attempts.

Comment: So I've answered below, but based on the "full case" you described, I'm not 100% it covers that. I suggest you put one of those examples in your reproducible dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1, 1, 2, 2], 'id':['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[3, 5, 5, 7], 'id':['A2', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4']})

df1 = df1[df1.id.isin(df2.id)]
df2 = df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]

df1['ones'] = 1
df1['counter'] = df1.groupby('id')['ones'].cumsum()
del df1['ones']

df2['ones'] = 1
df2['counter'] = df2.groupby('id')['ones'].cumsum()
del df2['ones']


df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'counter'], suffixes = ['_checkin', '_checkout'])
del df3['counter']

print(df3)

   date_checkin  id  date_checkout
0             1  A2              3
1             2  A2              5
2             2  A3              5
```

**Steps:**

Initialize dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1, 1, 2, 2], 'id':['A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[3, 5, 5, 7], 'id':['A2', 'A3', 'A2', 'A4']})
```

Filter down dataframes for only records that exist in each other, by `id`

```
df1 = df1[df1.id.isin(df2.id)]
df2 = df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
```

Create a `cumsum` counter to match on. This is where we will match on "first checkin" with "first checkout"

```
df1['ones'] = 1
df1['counter'] = df1.groupby('id')['ones'].cumsum()
del df1['ones']

df2['ones'] = 1
df2['counter'] = df2.groupby('id')['ones'].cumsum()
del df2['ones']
```

Now we can do an `inner join` on both `id` and `counter`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'counter'], suffixes = ['_checkin', '_checkout'])
del df3['counter']

print(df3)

   date_checkin  id  date_checkout
0             1  A2              3
1             2  A2              5
2             2  A3              5
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @matt, this really helps! I didn't think of using groupby with cumsum to get a unique key for the merge. So as long as I don't have a checkout before my first checkin, this should work perfectly!

Comment: No problem! If it does end up working, kindly accept the answer.